# Could a non-Force sensitive user destroy the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, death-star

In ANH, we see Luke destroy the Death Star by using the Force while the only other pilot (who is presumably not Force-sensitive) to attempt firing his missiles misses. Is there any indication in canon that it was required to be Force-sensitive to make the shot, or could an average pilot with enough luck make the shot?

Comment: In my experience, there's no such thing as luck.

Comment: Luke did say that any of his childhood friends could make similarly difficult shots. I also don't feel like looking up a clip that could easily be interpreted as Luke just being humble.

Comment: It's a very difficult shot, but not impossible (despite what Wedge says in the movie!). You don't need to use the Force to do it, although using the Force would probably make it easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be made by a normal person.

In *Rogue One* we learn that Galen Erso is the man responsible for the flaw. He had to keep it subtle or the Empire would have found it. But he's banking on someone exploiting it to destroy the Death Star. Erso has no way of knowing Force users exist, so clearly this has to be a task a normal person could do.

The reason the first shot fails is it's still a hard target to hit (harder still with a Tie fighter piloted by a Sith Lord chasing you). The pilots note this in the briefing. Being a Force user just made it easier.

Comment: Wasn`t Darth Vader flying a Tie Advance or to be more precise, the prototype of the Tie Advance and not a cute little Tie Fighter? 
I know that this is nitpicking.

Comment: Julian - A Tie Advance sounds like it might be a sub category of a Tie fighter.  It sounds to me like you are doing the equivalent of specifying an Iowa-class Battleship instead of a battleship, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely fair to describe the TIE Advanced as a subclass of the TIE. It outclassed TIEs in pretty much every capacity - faster, more heavily armoured/shielded and more heavily armed. That's a bit like saying a Porsche is a subclass of a VW Beetle. X-Wing's vs TIEs in a trench run, where the trench limits the TIEs primary advantages of numbers and manoeuvrability would have been much more one-sided, the TIE Advanced was a huge game-changer (and in fact if a TIE hitting Vader's ship didn't take him out of the fight, things might have gone very differently).